# Volley loading pictures with Header info in adapter

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-adapter, android-volley

I have a really big problem, i need to load pictures (on the fly) within my Adapter for ListView.

The problem is that pictures have 'Authorization access' and i need Override this to add Header info

```
 @Override
 public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
     setup tokens...
 return params;
 }
```

So for this reason i am using ImageRequest from Volley (coz only there i can setup headers), and i am getting OutOfMemory when i scroll the list.

Can you please tell me if you know other solutions to send image request with Header info?

Or how to prevent this OutOfMemory?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I tried lib AQuery

```
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(convertView);

    AjaxCallback<String> cb = new AjaxCallback<String>();
    cb.header(Consts.HEADER_APP_KEY, Consts.PREF_APP_KEY);
    aq.ajax(cb);
    aq.id(holder.profilePic).image(url, true, true, 0, 0, null, 0, 1.0f);
```

BUT IT'S NOT WORKING

Comment: you have to check out this awesome library for image loading https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: @Haresh how can i add header while requesting and image? I EDITED my post please see

Comment: can you please show me your header string ?

Comment: @Haresh Please write an answer i want to accept it, i used BitmapAjaxCallback and it worked!! THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ["Android Query"](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) async image loading library.